# Water suppose to continue to leak after brand new faucet install?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, faucet

Needed to hire a plumber and remembered that in my bathroom, I had turned the hot water valve off under the sink because it was leaking through the faucet at the time. It’s been off for a while, so I added this fix to my list of needs. He recommended a new faucet because he said with how old it was, would be easier. Ok. Bought new faucets to be installed. Fast forward and noticed a VERY SLOW drip in both sinks. Plumber came back and took out the water saver feature thinking that it could cause water to back up, then cause a leak. Well, both still leaked and now the hot water valve underneath, the one I  originally turned off, is now leaking. Plumber came back, took the handles off and didn’t notice any issue. Told me to place cup underneath and send a pic in the morning. I did and he called me and said that was nothing to worry about. Yes, the underneath valve does need to be replaced, but for both faucets to leak 1/4tsp amount in a 6 hour time period? None of my other faucets in the house, or the previous ones, have active water after a period of time. It’s dry. Am I missing something? Is this normal faucet activity?

Comment: No, new faucets should not leak _at all_, and the fact that your plumber considered removing the flow reducer to be a potential solution raises concerns about their qualification. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to ask about your actual problem rather than whether you should have one.

Comment: Leaks in a water system is saying something needs fixing.  Some taps might need a tiny bit of an extra turn to stop drips.  Condensation might cause drips on cold water lines if the house is warm and humid, but this does not sound like your problem.